# Is there a way to query a Julia Timer to see whether it is running or not?

Tags: timer, julia

Julia has a Timer object which can run a callback function at a set repetition rate. According to the [standard library](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/), the only functions using a Timer are start_timer() and stop_timer().

Is there a way, given a Timer, to check whether it is currently running or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best way to look for something like this is [`methodswith`](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/#Base.methodswith).  Unfortunately, there aren't many methods defined for Julia `Timer` objects:

```
julia> methodswith(Timer, true) # true to check super types, too (but not Any)
5-element Array{Method,1}:
 stop_timer(timer::Timer) at stream.jl:499
 close(t::Timer) at stream.jl:460
 start_timer(timer::Timer,timeout::Int64,repeat::Int64) at deprecated.jl:204
 start_timer(timer::Timer,timeout::Real,repeat::Real) at stream.jl:490
 close(t::Timer) at stream.jl:460
```

So we've got to dig a bit deeper. Looking at the [implementation for Timer](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/a6b610473ba72b6130826c513a7c3d6875f06cca/base/stream.jl#L449) reveals that it simply wraps a libuv timer object.  So I just did a search through [libuv/include/uv.h](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/blob/db2a9072bce129630214904be5e2eedeaafc9835/include/uv.h) for the timer API, and found [`int uv_is_active(const uv_handle_t* handle)`](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/blob/db2a9072bce129630214904be5e2eedeaafc9835/include/uv.h#L547-L567), which looks very promising. I simply wrap this c call in a Julian function, and it works like a charm:

```
julia> isactive(t::Timer) = bool(ccall(:uv_is_active, Cint, (Ptr{Void},), t.handle));

julia> t = Timer((x)->println(STDOUT,"\nboo"));

julia> isactive(t)
false

julia> start_timer(t, 10., 0); # fire in 10 seconds, don't repeat

julia> isactive(t)
true

julia>
boo
julia> isactive(t)
false
```